# Connecting a servo to a Pi

Tags: python, servo

I'm new to electronics and have run into a problem while trying to hook up my micro-servo to my Pi.

I have a Rapsberry Pi model 3 B, a breadboard, a 6V power supply, and a TowerPro MG90S micro servo.

The way I have everything wired is as followed:

- The battery supply is connected to the right side power rails, the black goes negative, the red to positive.
- The micro servo gets connected with the black wire going to negative, middle wire (orange/red) to positive, and the yellow wire goes directly to pin 11 (6th row, first pin) on my pi.
- Lastly, the ground pin on the pi (row 3, pin 2) is hooked up to negative on the right side of the power rail.

The code I'm using to test it I found online:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pin_number = 11
GPIO.setup(pin_number, GPIO.OUT)

frequency_hertz = 50
pwm = GPIO.PWM(pin_number, frequency_hertz)


left_position = 0.40
right_position = 2.5
middle_position = (right_position - left_position) / 2 + left_position


positionList = [left_position, middle_position, right_position, middle_position]


ms_per_cycle = 1000 / frequency_hertz

for i in range(3):
        for position in positionList:
                duty_cycle_percentage = position * 100 / ms_per_cycle
                print("Position: " + str(position))
                print("Duty Cycle: " + str(duty_cycle_percentage))
                print("")
                pwm.start(duty_cycle_percentage)
                time.sleep(.5)

pwm.stop()


GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run this, nothing happens. I don't know if the pi is faulty, the servo is, or something might be wired incorrectly.

Comment: Try adding a transistor to the signal wire on the servo.

Comment: Please make a wiring diagram/schematic.

Answer (score 1):

See https://pinout.xyz/ for the pin out of the Pi's 40-pin expansion header.

I'm assuming you have connected the servo control wire to GPIO 17.  I'm further assuming you have connected a Pi ground to the servo ground.

To see if your servo works enter the following commands.

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

pigs s 17 1000 # send 1000 micro pulses to servo
pigs s 17 1500 # send 1500 micro pulses to servo
pigs s 17 2000 # send 2000 micro pulses to servo
```

Comment: Yes, that all seems correct. It doesn't seem to respond to any of those commands. I almost wonder if the battery is not working correctly, but I don't have a volt meter to test it.

Comment: Forget the battery.   Power the servo from the Pi's 5V rail.  That should supply more than enough for a 9g servo or two or three.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I rebooted my pi and tried again, no luck.

Comment: You need to add a photo of your connections.  There is very little to go wrong with a servo.

Comment: Connections are messy, but I listed them all in the original post. I really think the servo is just broken.

Comment: Do you have an alternate servo or Arduino type based controller to test servo? Pi has overhead of an OS environment, and can jitter the PWM. 

Not sure if this is your issue, but look into using Software VS Hardware (DMA) based signaling. The software based will generate some jitter on the RPi, and might give you some problems while CPU threads through other processes, leaving the PWM to not be as steady. 

"there is one hardware PWM output on the Raspberry Pi, connected to P1-12 (GPIO18). "   -  try pin 18?

Pi and Servo sharing common ground and power?

Comment: @mrSidX There are two hardware PWM channels connected to GPIO 12/13/18/19 on the expansion header.  pigs/pigpiod uses hardware timed PWM on any of GPIO 0-31 which is fine for servos/ESCs.